# TV remote mystery

Tags: wireless, electromagnetic, transmitter, wave

My TV remote has this hole. The hole exists for the propagation of the EM waves coming from inside the remote correct? I guess plastic would absorb those EM waves and we don't want that to happen.

[image]

And now my 2nd question TV remote are powered from batteries DC sources. But an EM wave is created by the motion of charges back and forth changing motion does my remote have inside it a DC to AC converter?

Comment: As a matter of practical *efficiency* it might be useful to try looking things like this up before posting a question, eg "how does a TV remote work"...

Comment: This remote, like most TV remotes, uses infrared light. My Roku remote uses RF (radio frequency). RF travels well through plastic, the Roku remote has no holes.

Comment: "mystery" isn't the right word to use when you haven't tried to google...

Answer (score 5):

Technically infrared light is an EM wave, yes.

But it behaves a lot more like the light you are used to seeing, just at a color you cannot.

You're looking down the barrel of an IR LED.  While the light production is from the movement of charge across a semiconductor band gap (you can go look up how an LED works) it does so when simply fed a DC current.

However, your remote does not simply turn on the LED, rather it sends pulses (probably at 38 KHz) and encodes commands as sequences of some number of them, then a gap, then some more and so on.  So technically, the electrical signal to the LED is AC with a DC component, which is usefully termed "pulsed DC".

The receiver in the TV then look for pulses of that frequency, and outputs a signal matching their pattern of presence/absence, which the MCU in the TV decodes into commands.

Answer (score 3):

> The hole exists for the propagation of the EM waves coming from inside the remote correct?

Yes. The EM waves coming from the remote are infrared (IR) light. While it is possible to make plastic that is opaque to visible light but transparent to IR, it's cheaper to just make ordinary opaque plastic with a hole in it.

The surface you see inside the hole is the top of the IR LED that produces the IR light.

> But an EM wave is created by the motion of charges back and forth changing motion does my remote have inside it a DC to AC converter?

As mentioned above, the EM wave is produced by an LED. In the case of an LED, the EM wave (light) isn't produced by moving charge but by the transition of charged particles between energy states in the semiconductor material.

But inside the remote there is also an oscillator circuit that produces a changing voltage that is used to turn the LED on and off, typically at a rate of 35-45 kHz.

The 35-45 kHz drive signal is further modulated by another, slower, pattern that depends on which button you push, and again a circuit is used to produce this modulation pattern.

Comment: The signal transmitted is not unlike that of a 1 data wire interface, albeit unidirectional and slow. Almost like RS232 !

Answer (score 2):

What you show is an infrared remote, with an exposed IR LED. IR remotes are basically like fancy LED flashlights, sending pulsed light from the LED to the receiving device. If your eye could see the IR, it would look like a rapid flicker. Some remotes drive a visible LED with the same signal as the IR to show activity.

Some IR remotes hide the LED behind IR-transparent plastic (for example, the black Tivo ‘peanut’ remotes), but nevertheless work the same as those with an exposed LED.

Inside, the remote’s microcontroller scans the keypad and forms the pulse train to make a data signal for the pressed key, which drives the LED. There’s many different ways do that, the most common being the NEC and RC-5 (Phillips) standards.

Typical data rate for IR remotes is about 2Kbps.

RF remotes on the other hand use radio modulation instead of (or in addition to) infrared. Plastic is transparent to RF, so the signal emits from the remote practically unimpeded.

RF remotes use protocol standards like Bluetooth, RF4CE or even Wi-Fi (e.g., Roku), or use simpler approaches such as just making an RF version of the IR signal. Data rates for these vary, from 64Kbps (RF4CE) to 1-2Mbit/s (BLE2, Wi-Fi) depending on the standard used.

The RF remote micro contains an RF transmitter or transceiver, typically integrated as part of the controller.

(I personally have designed IR, RF4CE and Bluetooth (BLE) remotes.)

Comment: "If your eye could see the IR, it would look like a rapid flicker." indeed, and the camera preview on your phone probably can; maybe less so if it's an iDevice as they try harder than most to filter IR, but perhaps still...

Comment: @ChrisStratton iPhone, nothing. iPad, nothing. Sony DSLR- the "characteristic purple from IR" colored light and flicker, but not especially bright- red indicator LED is much brighter even from the side.

Comment: Fun fact: the back camera has an IR filter, the front camera does not.